# WriteFile returning error 1784

Tags: c++, winapi, writefile

I am creating a program to populate a disk with a dummy file system.

Currently, I am writing files of variable sizes using `WriteFile`.

```
        WriteFile(hFile, FileData, i * 1024, &dwWrote, NULL);
        err = GetLastError();
```

err returns #1784 which translates to

> The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation.     ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER

So for the first 24 files, the write operation works.  For file #25 on, the write operation fails.
The files are still created but the WriteFile function does not populate the files.

Any ideas on how to get past `ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER`?

Every reference I can find to the error is limited to crashing programs and I cannot figure out how it relates to the issue I am experiencing.

EDIT:

```
FileData = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (size_t)k * 1024);
memset(FileData, 245, sizeof(char) * (size_t)k * 1024);
```

FileData is set and allocated to the size of the maximum anticipate buffer.
i is the loop variable that iterates until it increments to the Maximum Size (k).

Comment: How are we to know what type those parameters have, and what you've done with them previously?

Comment: Also, note that crashing is usually a result of UB (which, itself, is usually trying to access invalid memory). However, crashing is not _always_ the result of UB. It's unpredictable as to what might occur. So if you expect a crash that's not occurring, don't read too much into it.

Comment: The WriteFile function may fail with ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER or ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY whenever there are too many outstanding asynchronous I/O requests.

Comment: This is not async I/O, `LPOVERLAPPED` is null.  Far more likely a simple buffer misuse imo.  That said, without code it's hard to be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `FileData` is not large enough for you to write `i * 1024` bytes from it.  Is `i` the loop control variable for your list of files?  If so, you need the write buffer `FileData` to grow 1K at a time as you loop through your files.

This is an unusual construct.  Are you sure the logic is correct here?  Post more code (specifically, all usage of `FileData` and `i`) for better accuracy in the answers.

Note that you should not always be checking `GetLastError` here - you need to check `WriteFile`'s return code before you rely on that being meaningful.  Otherwise you could be picking up an error from some unrelated part of your code - whatever failed last.

Comment: Updated original post with more details

Comment: Also, WriteFile returns 0 on fail when dwWrote is 0.

Comment: It's really impossible to offer accurate advice based on random snippets of code.  Get a minimally-sufficient to repro the error and then post it all.

Comment: Your comment above proved correct.  Buffer was being reallocated to improper size.

Answer (score 2):

I got a Error = 1784 and it was because I opened the file without specifying the size of records and then did block reads on the file.

```
Reset( FileHandle );
```

Should be

```
Reset( FileHandle, 1 );
```